# Is this a proper/secure way to log someone in?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, session-cookies, flask-login

Okay, I'm really new to programming (just learned how to make database connections and write/read from it today) and I'm trying to make a basic site that allows you to log a user in, and have some sort of page that is different when a user is logged in. I've decided to take a stab using Flask, Flask-session, Sqlite3, basically authentication is as follows: user logs in using form, form data is checked against the information in sqlite3 database, then if it is correct, the corresponding values are written to the CLIENT-side cookie. Is this an acceptable way of logging someone in? Forgive my ignorance, but I am really new to programming and I'm missing some key terminology to search for my own answers here. I've searched around, but haven't been able to determine if this is a accepted way to do logins/out.

My site works, but I don't know if I'm actually logging anything in or out in the traditional sense. Also notice some routes are weirdly broken or hidden this is just cause of me trying to break things to see how they work. To get my site running, I didn’t include the templates:

`from app.py import init_db`

`init_db()`

`python app.py`

Here's my app file:

```
#importations
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
abort, render_template, flash, escape
from contextlib import closing
import sys
import datetime
from models import User
from formms import RegistrationForm, Login
import os


key1 = os.urandom(24)
#config
DATABASE = '/tmp/fitty1.db'
DEBUG = True
SECRET_KEY = key1
USERNAME = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'default'
print key1

#Initialize the application
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

#login_manager = LoginManager()
#login_manager.init_app(app)




#Method to connect to database, use to open a connection on request, or from interactive python shell
def connect_db():
    return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

#Run this before application to initialize the DB
def init_db():
    with closing(connect_db()) as db:
        with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()


def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv



@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    db = getattr(g, 'db', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    g.db = connect_db()
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)


@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    g.db = connect_db()
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        user = User(form.username.data, form.email.data, form.password.data)
        g.db.execute('insert into users (username, email, password) values (?, ?, ?)',
             [request.form['username'], request.form['email'], request.form['password']])
        g.db.commit()
        flash('Registered successfully')
        return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)


@app.route('/account') 
def account():
    g.db = connect_db()
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    if 'username' in session:
        username = session['username']
        c = g.db.execute("SELECT password from users where username = (?)", (username,))
        passwc = c.fetchone()
        c = g.db.execute("SELECT text from entries")
        texty = c.fetchone()
        return 'Your username is "%s", your password is "%s" and code %s' % (username, passwc[0], texty[0])
    return 'You are not logged in'


@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    g.db = connect_db()
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    g.db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
                 [request.form['title'], request.form['text']])
    g.db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully added')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    g.db = connect_db()
    error = None
    form = Login(request.form)
    user = User(form.username.data, form.email.data, form.password.data)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        c = g.db.execute("SELECT username from users where username = (?)", [form.username.data])
        userexists = c.fetchone()
        if userexists:
            c = g.db.execute("SELECT password from users where password = (?)", [form.password.data])
            passwcorrect = c.fetchone()
            if passwcorrect:
                session['username'] = form.username.data
                session['logged_in'] = True
                flash('You were logged in')
                return redirect(url_for('account'))
            else:
                return 'password fail'
        else:
            return 'username fail'
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    g.db = connect_db()
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged Out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))




#Use build in server to run standalone application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Models

```
import sqlite3
from flask import g
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, login_required

class User():
    def __init__(self,username,email,password,active=True):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.active = active

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
        #Return true if authenticated, provided credentials

    def is_active(self):
        return True

def is_anonymous(self):
    return False
    #return true if anon, actual user returns false


def __repr__(self):
    return '<User %r>' % (self.email)
```

Schema.sql

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  title text not null,
  text text not null
);
drop table if exists users;
create table users (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  username text not null,
  email text not null,
  password text not null
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's absolutely the way to do it. The client side cookie allows you to uniquely identify a user. You just have to make sure the cookie is sufficiently randomized, otherwise someone could spoof it.

If your cookie for me was `uid=hailey` that would be bad because I could easily edit that to be `uid=ach1lles` and get your admin access. Instead, you want to do something sufficiently random, like a base64 of a sha2 hash of my username and the current time and the headline of yesterday's NYT or something crazy like that. You would want to add this as a database table, and then check it when I make a request.

Also, don't store the password as text, consider something like bcrypt. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However, to my current understanding I think Flask sessions cryptographically signs cookies, wouldn't this mean that the user can't modify the cookie itself? Also thanks for tip about bcrypt, implementing now!

Comment: The user can always modify a cookie - it's just a line of text in the HTTP request. Whether or not a user is capable of modifying it to something useful is another story. If what you say is true, Flask has taken the liberty of doing exactly what I was describing in the second half of my second paragraph which is good - they probably do it better!!! Use an extension like Chrome's EditThisCookie, or watch the traffic in Fiddler, to verify that when you put `uid=hailey` it actually becomes `uid=8ebc8d6af18` or something. If it does, then what you're doing is spot on!

Comment: You really really *really* want to make sure your stored passwords are encrypted *and* salted while stored in the database (preferably with a strong one-way hash). This also helps make sure that, if the database is dumped (eg. SQL injection), obtaining username and passwords isn't terribly straightforward. Though I'm still fairly new at Flask, I'm sure there are libraries to help with this sort of thing.

Comment: RVT: note taken, thank you! I started hashing the passwords, and and checking hashes at login instead of plain text. Looking into furthering the security by somehow encrypting username and still playing nicely with my session.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't actually encrypt the username - you can hash it, but it's only obscuring it - you can't salt it uniquely because you have no way of looking up a unique salt. When securing a system you should assume your intruder knows what methods you're using to encrypt - that's why having a unique salt is so important. If you have a single salt, they'll generate a giant "rainbow table" and get, well, everything.

Answer (score 1):

Your second SELECT query exposes a security risk. Someone can log in as any user simply by knowing the password of any one user.

Imagine you have the following users (ignoring that the passwords are plaintext):

```
username | password
---------+---------
Jack     | abc123
-------------------
Jill     | def456
```

Let's say someone attempts to log in with "Jack" as the username and "def456" as the password.

Your first SELECT

```
c = g.db.execute("SELECT username from users where username = (?)", [form.username.data])
```

is going to return the record for Jack. This causes you to execute your second SELECT

```
c = g.db.execute("SELECT password from users where password = (?)", [form.password.data])
```

This is going to return the record for Jill. While this is a different user, you only check for a record returned from the query, not the same record as the first query. The user will be logged in as Jack even though they got Jack's password wrong.

Ideally you want to perform only one query, based on username, and compare the submitted password to the one in the database.

```
c = g.db.execute("SELECT username, password from users where username = (?)", [form.username.data])
user = c.fetchone()
# don't forget to apply your hashing algorithm to form.password.data
if user and user[1] == form.password.data:  
    session['username'] = form.username.data
    session['logged_in'] = True
    flash('You were logged in')
    return redirect(url_for('account'))
```

All that said, I can't recommend libraries like [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Flask-Security](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) enough. Authentication is hard to get right. Leverage the community to make it easier.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the comments, I fixed my username/password calls like you suggested and implemented pw_hashing on registering side. _One quick question though,_  the `if user and user[1] == form.password.data:`  how does this work? What is "user" in this case and how are the two values compared against form.password.data?

Comment: I see that the user=c.fetchone() call which returns some type with two values that are then compared against form.password.data is this correct? and how are the two compared against a single type. Also what type is this? `(u'lolcat', u'what')`

Comment: The if checks that `user` has a truthy value, just as your were checking originally. If that check passes, the if then checks that `user[1]` is equal to `form.password.data`. `fetchone` returns a tuple. With this SELECT, `user[0]` contains the username and `user[1]` contains the password.

Comment: Oh gotcha so the `if user` is a separate command from the password check. Thanks, now I understand `and`